# How do I pass optional arguments in JSON to bitcoin-cli createwallet without using curl?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli

I need to create an encrypted blank wallet, and for this purpose I need to furnish
`bitcoin-cli --testnet createwallet testwallet` with two more optional arguments.
Let the passphrase be "k3YQN3JOtyHMlRCg4v4". How do I do this?

I came across this example from `bitcoin-cli help createwallet`:

```
curl --user myusername --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id": "curltest", "method": "createwallet", "params": ["testwallet"]}' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332/
```

Whereas I've used `curl` before for scraping I would rather avoid using just creating a wallet?

I have already figured out a way of how to do this using -named:

```
/home/jerzy/bitcoin/bin/bitcoin-cli --testnet -named createwallet wallet_name=testwtwo blank=true passphrase=k3YQN3JOtyHMlRCg4v4
```

Now, I would like to do the same by passing the optional argumets in JSON.
I've tried all the following but to no avail:

```
/home/jerzy/bitcoin/bin/bitcoin-cli --testnet createwallet testwtwo '{ "blank":"true", "passphrase":"k3YQN3JOtyHMlRCg4v4" }'
error code: -1
error message:
JSON value is not a boolean as expected

/home/jerzy/bitcoin/bin/bitcoin-cli --testnet createwallet testwtwo '{ "blank":true, "passphrase":"k3YQN3JOtyHMlRCg4v4" }'
error code: -1
error message:
JSON value is not a boolean as expected

/home/jerzy/bitcoin/bin/bitcoin-cli --testnet createwallet testwtwo '{ blank : true, passphrase : "k3YQN3JOtyHMlRCg4v4" }'
error: Error parsing JSON: { blank : true, passphrase : "k3YQN3JOtyHMlRCg4v4" }
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> bitcoin-cli --testnet -named createwallet wallet_name=testwtwo blank=true passphrase=k3YQN3JOtyHMlRCg4v4

Doing same thing without using `-named`

```
bitcoin-cli -testnet createwallet testwtwo false true k3YQN3JOtyHMlRCg4v4
```